# Why first letter in array of strings don't convert to upper case?

Tags: javascript

I take on input string `"ZpglnRxqenU"`

and must return string with that view 
`"Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu"`

i almost done, but i don't know why first letter in array elements don't change to upper case.

```js
function accum(s) {
  let str = s.toLowerCase();
  let arr = [];
  
  for(let i=0; i<str.length;i++){
      arr.push(str[i].repeat(i+1));
      arr[i][0].toUpperCase();
  }
  
  return arr.join('-');
}



console.log(accum("ZpglnRxqenU"));

// must be "Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu"
```

Comment: As a side note you can write a one-liner like `'ZpglnRxqenU'.split('').map((el, i) => el.toUpperCase() + el.repeat(i).toLowerCase()).join('-')`

Comment: @connexo: Your example in your comment above (`arr[i][0]=arr[i][0].toUpperCase()`) won't work because you are also trying to modify the string.

Comment: @Teemoh Indeed, that's why I changed it to `arr[i] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);` in my answer. Couldn't modify the comment quick enough, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in Javascript are **immutable**, so it's got to be `arr[i] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1)` if you want to convert it.

`toUpperCase()`  only *returns*  the character(s), **it won't manipulate the String** it was called on.

The same is true for any other method on `String.prototype` like e.g. `String.replace()`.

**To make it even more clear: The only way in Javascript to ever change a variable containing a String is *assigning a new value*  to the variable.**

```js
function accum(s) {
  let str = s.toLowerCase();
  let arr = [];
  
  for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
      arr.push(str[i].repeat(i+1));
      arr[i] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);
  }
  
  return arr.join('-');
}



console.log(accum("ZpglnRxqenU"));
```

Comment: yea, i try to with that way `arr[i][0]=arr[i][0].toUpperCase()`, but it anyway was return strings with lower case.
http://jsfiddle.net/51pfj3gc/5/

Comment: Yes, because that was another attempt to treat the String as an array and modify part of it (`arr[i][0]`) without reassigning the **variable**. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable and just using .toUpperCase() will not update existing string, to do that you can try below code

```
function accum(s) {
  let str = s.toLowerCase();
  let arr = [];

  for(let i=0; i<str.length;i++){
      arr.push(str[i].repeat(i+1));
      var [firstLetter, ...rest] = arr[i]
      arr[i] = firstLetter.toUpperCase() +rest.join('')
  }

  return arr.join('-');
}
```

Comment: This requires the use of Babel to be compatible with IE 11 and lower.

Comment: @connexo yes, for object destructuring support complier is required in IE. But is it not ok to make use of latest features and use complier for IE, also full support is already there in Chrome, any thoughts that may be helpful for me for my upcoming answers?

Comment: Ofc it is okay, but it should be noted when applied on a IE11-compatible-code-based question.

Comment: Thank you @connexo, though I am not sure question mentioned "E11-compatible-code-based question" anywhere. Nonethless thanks.

Comment: It didn't mention that, but code was IE11-compatible to start with. So suggesting a solution that ends this compatibility is perfectly fine, but helpful to at least mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You can to do it like this way and remove unnecessary this line `arr[i][0].toUpperCase();`

```js
function accum(s) {
  let str = s.toLowerCase();
  let arr = [];
  
  for(let i=0; i<str.length;i++){
      let gStr = str[i].repeat(i+1);
      arr.push(gStr[0].toUpperCase() + gStr.slice(1));
  } 
  return arr.join('-');
}
console.log(accum("ZpglnRxqenU"));
```

Comment: Isn't `gStr.charAt(0)` just a verbose way of doing `gStr[0]`?

Comment: @connexo agreed sir. Done **Editing**

Answer (score 0):

You could take the power of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and get the string in characters and map the first upper case character and the repeated characters for a new string.

At the end join all items to a single string.

```js
function accum(s) {
    return Array
        .from(s.toLowerCase(), (c, i) => c.toUpperCase() + c.repeat(i))
        .join('-');
}

console.log(accum("ZpglnRxqenU"));
```